# Making tabs navbar sticky with tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to make my navbar for my tabs sticky so that when I scroll down the page to look at the items for each tab page.

The tab navbar stays in the same place so that I do not need to scroll up to change the selected tab.

I had tried sticky, and fixed on the nav part but that did not work.

```
  <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 lg:col-span-3 ">
    <div className="p-6">
      <div className="relative">
           <div className="relative  sm:overflow-hidden">
            <div className="hidden sm:block">
                  <div className="border-b border-gray-200">
                    <nav
                      className="-mb-px flex space-x-8 overflow-x-auto"
                      aria-label="Tabs"
                    >
```

Comment: Try using `sticky` again, but make sure you set a value for top e.g. `top-0`.

Comment: the issue is the nav isn't at the top of the page. so top-0 won't work for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet to your question, i suggest you make the parent container to be fixed and have its position top and left to be 0

```
export const Navbar = () => {
 return (
  <div className="top-0 left-0 p-4 fixed bg-black w-full">
   <div className="flex justify-between">
    <div>
      <h2 className="font-bold text-lg">Logo</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul className="flex gap-x-4">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

);
};

Comment: the issue is the nav isn't at the top of the page. so top-0 won't work for that.

Comment: can u share a codepen or sandbox to your code lemme bank on it